# Electron automatic updates fail - code signing issues on Windows

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

Our latest Electron production build is failing to automatically update on clients. We are using `electron-builder: v23.0.2` to handle the automatic updates through electron-updater and we have not changed our code signing certificate.

electron-updater downloads the automatic update but fails to update with the following error:

```
Electron auto-update error: Error: New version 4.0.0 is not signed by the application owner: publisherNames: Developer ID Application: OUR COMPANY NAME, LLC (123F2ASF2), raw info: {
.....
"Status": 1,
"StatusMessage": "A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority"
```

I have tried rebuilding the app from a machine running Windows and MacOS, using the same code signing certificate with the following script:

```
yarn build && cross-env CSC_LINK=../code-sign-certificate.p12 CSC_KEY_PASSWORD=password \
    electron-builder build --config ./electron-builder/$environment-config.json --$platform \
    -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js -c.extraMetadata.version=$version \
    --publish never
```

I've confirmed that our certificate has not expired. The resulting auto-update error has been the same for all new builds. ):

Any thoughts on what could be causing the `"A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority"` message?

Comment: The problem is not a possibly expired certificate of yours, but that the certificate you have used to sign the application with cannot be verified against known and trusted certificate authorities the operating system has in its truststore. Thus, check if e.g. Windows' file properties display the signature correctly. Also, it may be worthwhile to check which root certificate of your CA was used to generate and sign your certificate. There may be something wrong with that (e.g. that this root has expired although that seems unlikely).

Comment: Of course, all of the above only applies if you can confirm that it's the very same PKCS keystore file you have used to sign your current version (that is currently signed and working).

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Thanks for the reply. I was able to confirm that the digital signatures on the previous builds are the same as the most recent (on my Windows machine, I right clicked on both `.exe` files -> Digital Signatures and confirmed both are the same certificate from DigiCert.) Any suggestions for how I can check the validity of the root certificate?